# Combinations of up to $n$ out of $m$ elements

Tags: combinations

Given a set of $m$ unique elements to choose from, and using at most $n$ elements in a combination, how many combinations can I have? A combination can repeat an element more than once, as long as the number of items does not exceed $n$ elements. Order of elements does not matter.

For example, say I have $100$ elements, and I want to find out how many combinations I could make of $10$ elements or fewer, if a combination can include repeats?

Comment: Did you mean to say using at most $n$ elements in a combination?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sorry, yes. Already edited.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I've kind of been stumped from the start. This is just a small problem I faced in a personal programming project, but it's not really programming-related on its own so I think it belongs here. I have only a basic knowledge of mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter, then you need the fact that the number of ways to choose $r$ objects from a set of $m$ is $C(m+r-1,r)~~$. Then your answer will be
$$\sum_{i=0}^n C(m+i-1,i).$$ (This is an abbreviation for
$C(m+0-1,0) + C(m+1-1,1) + \cdots + C(m+n-1,n)~~~~$.)

Comment: What does C stand for?

Comment: @LukeTaylor : $C(n,r)$ is the notation for the number of subsets of an $n$-element set that have exactly $r$ elements in them. It also is the binomial coefficient ${n\choose r}$ and is also sometimes written as $nCr$. Formula: $\displaystyle C(n,r) = {n! \over r! (n-r)!}$

Comment: @hardmath : The $C(m+r-1,r)$ formula allows repetition of elements. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition )

Comment: Perhaps I've misinterpreted the problem.  I thought the repetitions were included in the $m=100$ items, and might vary with the distinct items included, e.g. letters of "Mississippi".  But if unlimited repetitions of $m=100$ distinct items is envisioned, then I agree your "stars-and-bars" approach will apply.

Comment: I'm interpretting the problem in the following way: Suppose $m=2$ and $n=3$; then (if the set is $\{1,2\}$), I'm counting the sets $\emptyset$, $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,1\}$, $\{2,2\}$, $\{1,1,1\}$, $\{1,1,2\}$, $\{1,2,2\}$, $\{2,2,2\}$.

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman I clarified in my problem. Have I entered this problem correctly into Wolfram|Alpha: http://i.imgur.com/boHqUkr.png? if $m$ is $3549860$ and $n$ is $10$?

Comment: It looks like it. (BTW, the formula above works even if $n>m$.)